# LocalName is returning empty string, though namespace is defined

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

**XML**

```
<em:Employees  xmlns:em="http://www.example.com">
    <em:Employee id="1">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Pankaj</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>Java Developer</role>
        <childrens>
            <child>
                <age>2</age>
                <name>Guptha</name>
                <gender>Male</gender>
            </child>
        </childrens>
    </em:Employee>
</em:Employees>
```

**Java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLParserSAX {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
        saxParser.parse(new File("src/Resources/employees.xml"), handler);
        //Get Employees list
        List<Employee> empList = handler.getEmpList();
        //print employee information
        for (Employee emp : empList)
            System.out.println(emp);
    }
}
```

In my DefaultHandler, when I'm implementing `startElement()`, `localName` is empty, and `qName` contains the namespace including the name, ex. `em:Employees`.

If I'm not mistaken, `localName` should give me back the name without the namespace. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It works for me, can you share the relevant part of the code? specially the part where you create the `XMLReader`

Comment: @morgano I'm not using XMLReader, I'm using SAXParser. I have posted my code above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try making the SAXParserFactory namespace aware:

```
    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    saxParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
```

Read the details of startElement() [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html). You'll see that `localName`isn' defined unless the parser is aware of namespaces.